# How can i Set up a Bluetooth connection between my react-native expo app and HC-06

Tags: react-native, android-bluetooth

I'm currently working on a React Native Expo app where I need to establish Bluetooth communication with an Arduino Uno board equipped with an HC-06 Bluetooth module. From what i understand it require Bluetooth classic and not low energy Bluetooth.

My question is how can i set up this workflow?

So far, i set up the Arduino code.